# Do flat ethernet cables perform as well as regular cables?

Tags: ethernet, layer1, cable

I came across some flat ethernet cables ([like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00R77LOFO)) and was thinking of picking some up, but I have no idea if their performance would be degraded compared to regular cables.

Does anyone know anything about them?

Comment: I have no practical experience with them, but if they're rated CAT-6, then they should perform to that specification.

Comment: It work well if it good manufactured, same as simple cables. Usually flat cables cost more, but It good for example for travel as it lightweight and compact. Of course can be risky to use it in SCS as it can exceed 100 m  line limit, but it fit for end to end connection.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the manufacturer may claim Category-6, but the UTP standard says that patch cords cannot exceed 5 meters, and this claims 100'.

It is highly unlikely that this cable can actually pass the Category-6 suite for patch cords in all the other tests in the suite (it *will* fail for length).  If you happen to get one, get it tested on a high-end tester that can test the Category-6 suite.

At speeds up to 1 Gb, Category-5E and Category-6 will both either work at the full 1 Gb, or they are not properly installed.  A cable system only gets the rating of the lowest rated component (horizontal cable, terminations, patch panels, patch cords, etc.) in the system.  Buying Category-6 anything to add to a lower rated system is a waste of money.

Comment: *"Buying Category-6 anything to add to a lower rated system is a waste of money."* Unless, of course, you are in the process of upgrading said system to cat-6.